# Unable to create table in database getting warning

Tags: spring-boot

Getting Wrnings but unable to create tables in data base.

while executing spring boot program I am getting this.
HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead

HHH90000026: MySQL57Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
[2m

Comment: Please add the create table code.

Comment: This is clear springboot issue, it is not related to MySQL. Fix it in your application code.